# Access coordinates on CosmosDb Location object when using LINQ to SQL translation

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

I need an elegant way to emit longitude and latitude from CosmosDb using LINQ to SQL Translation. I do not want to emit the entire `Location` object.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Spatial;

namespace Foo.Bar 
{
    public class DataInCosmos : BaseEntity // which has `string Id`
    {
        public string Pk { get; set; }
        public Point Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Json translation from the Point object does not exist ... trying to use the helper methods on point:

- LINQ `Location.Position.Longitude` => SQL `root["location"]["coordinates"]["Longitude"]` which does not exist and so returns `0`
- LINQ `Location.Position.Coordinates[0]` => `root["location"]["coordinates"]["Coordinates"][0]` which again does not exist, so returns `0`

I tried creating my own `Point` class ... but then I lose the polygon search functionality from the `Point` class that my code relies on.

My workaround is to create a udf:

```js
/**
 * LOCATION_COORD_BY_INDEX
 *
 * returns item in location.coordinate by its index: 0=long, 1=lat, 2=altitude
 */

function main(loc, i) {
    return loc ? loc.coordinates[i] : null;
}
```

Then use that in the LINQ string as so

```cs
 Longitude = (double)CosmosLinq.InvokeUserDefinedFunction("LOCATION_COORD_BY_INDEX", x.Location, 0)
```

This works ... but surely there is an easier, native way ... or is this a bug in CosmosDb SDK 3?

Comment: May be related to serialiser version issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2304 ... but my code uses NewtonSoft as per the SDK v3

Comment: Source for `Position` is at https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Spatial/Position.cs